# Best way to implement undo?

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

Our app successfully adds content to OneNote and we would like to support an undo feature.  I already add a unique data-id to any content that the app adds.

Therefore looking at the REST api it looks like I need to do the following:

1) Get the entire page content with generated IDs

2) Parse the HTML to find the div I want to remove (using the data-id).  Find the generated id.

3) Issue a replace command with the generated id, replacing with empty content.

This seems a little convoluted so is there a better way to achieve this?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

If the app created the content and specified a unique data-id (during the POST), then OneNote will preserve that data-id. So assuming the content is still intact, you **could** avoid steps #1,2 if you already know the data-id and go straight to step #3.

Using the replace action with PATCH Pages is the way to go.

Comment: Hi Dipak, That doesn't work as I get a "PATCH target DIV for action replace is not supported".  This is confirmed by the documentation: For replace actions, you must use the generated ID for all elements except for the page title and images and objects that are within a div.